# Redirect www domain to http

Tags: apache, apache2, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I am having a hard time in trying to redirect all www requests to http in apache.

in http.conf i have:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(([a-z0-9_]+\.)?test\.pt/.*)$
RewriteRule .? http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

then i configured the following virtual host configured:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin xxx@yyy.pt                                                                        
     ServerName test.pt
     DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/testjoomla"
</VirtualHost>
```

So if I try to access: www.test.pt or www.test.pt/index.php/pt/ it works well it redirect to http://test.pt or http://test.pt/index.php/pt/ however if I try to access www.test.pt/index.php/pt do not works it keeps the www.test.pt/index.php/pt ... Can anyone give any help ?

Best regards

Comment: Could you please show us the log of the rewrite engine, as explained [in the httpd manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog)?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work instead?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(([a-z0-9_]+\.)?test\.pt.*)$
RewriteRule /(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Odd. Are those the only rewrite rules present in the config?

Comment: Yes. The redirect works as i said for www.test.pt or www.test.pt/index.php/pt/ however do not work for www.test.pt/index.php/pt